# Linearity and Integrating factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) - 3x = e^{-t }$$

Is this a linear function?

The reason why I'm asking is because I am choosing the method that I should do my integration. (exact method, separation, integrating factors)

Comment: @erfink so that means that we cannot use Integrating Factors or Separation Method?

Comment: @erfink I fixed the original problem, it is dx/dt not dt/dx

Comment: If it's $\frac{dx}{dt}$, then it is linear and we can use integrating factors.

Comment: @erfink wouldn't it only be non-linear if it was $e^{-x}$? Integrating factor with $e^{-3t}$ can be used here..

Comment: @erfink how is it linear if it doesn't follow the format: dy/dx + P(x)y = Q(x) ??

Comment: @RobertMiller It does follow that format - $P(t)=-3$, and $Q(t)=e^{-t}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right) - 3x = e^{-t }$$
$$e^t\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right) - 3xe^t = e^{-t}\cdot e^t=1$$
Notice that by chain rule $\frac{d(e^{t(x)})}{dx}=e^t \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$
$$\left(\frac{d(e^t)}{dx}\right) - 3xe^t = 1$$

Let $y=e^t(x)$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} -3xy = 1$$

So it is a linear ODE, or more precisely, could be transformed into a linear ODE.

**EDIT per update of question**

Now it becomes 
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) - 3x = e^{-t }$$

Notice here, $x,t$ are two just variable names, and you could re-name $x$ as $y$, and $t$ as $x$, then you get:
$$\left(\frac{dy }{dx }\right) - 3y = e^{-x }$$

With $P(x) = -3$ and $Q(x)=e^{-x}$
Then you do not need to do any transformation, it is readily a linear ODE.

Comment: dx/dt not dt/dx

Comment: @RobertMiller the original question is dt/dx, and OP updated it.

Comment: how did you get your second step? can you show more for that please?

Comment: @RobertMiller Sure, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am struggling to see how you get 3xe^t and just 1 on the right side..

Comment: @RobertMiller No problem

Comment: @RobertMiller Multiply both sides by $e^t$

Comment: So in this case for integrating factors it would be P(x) = 3x right?

Comment: Where we follow the format: dy/dx + p(x)y = q(x) ?

Comment: @RobertMiller notice for the updated equation, $p(t) = -3,  q(t)=e^{-t}$, let me know if you still have trouble, I'll explain more.

Comment: @RobertMiller I updated my answer as well.

Comment: it still does not make sense what my P(x) or Q(x) would be in this.. if you mutliply everything by e^t you then have to divide by e^t so that you can get it in linear form

Comment: based on what you have edited, that would be NON-Linear as it has Q(x) = e^(-t) not an X ...

Comment: @RobertMiller I've updated my answer to show you P, Q. Notice you cannot multiply $e^x$, because you do not want anything coupled with $y'$

Comment: @RobertMiller notice that linear here is in terms of $y$ and its derivatives, not about $x$. Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Comment: so in this case dx/dt + p(t)x = q(t) where p(t) is -3?

Comment: @RobertMiller yes, you are correct! It's a constant function of t, it maps any values of t into the value of -3

Comment: now it makes sense, thank you

Comment: @RobertMiller no problem!